# Testing FTP connection through HTTP proxy

Tags: windows, http, testing, ftp, http-proxy

I would like to allow my application to connect to remote FTP server through HTTP proxy. My main problem is how to setup test environment for this. This is Windows only application written in C++. Can you recommend any HTTP proxy implementation that is easy to install and configure on Windows and can be used for testing?

Comment: [HTTP proxy server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734572/http-proxy-server?rq=1) has some links you might find useful in the accepted answer.